# Close what is already already running when running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drjava

i was wondering if in eclipse there is a way for eclipse, when you press the play button(run), it closes the already running program. For example, if anyone has every used Dr. Java, when you click run it basically closes all the running, compiled, programs and opens what ever you want to run. I was hopinmg there is a way to do this in eclipse because i often forget to close the program before running a modified version.

Also in Dr. Java it says something around the lines of "resetting interactions pane" so if that helps?

Comment: Do you mean other programs/project that are run through Eclipse? Is the Progress View what you are looking for?

Comment: @lindonfox no what i mean is that when i click run and i run my program, i dont usually remember to close that instance of the program before running it again. Dr. Java took care of that by closing all running instances when running a new instance

Answer (score 0):

Open the Debug View and you can kill all of the running processes launched from Eclipse.
[image: Picture of the Debug **Perspective**, but you can open the View from anywhere]

Comment: i dont mean like i have to go out of my way to do it, i mean like it automatically does it when i press run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching`, and check `Terminate and Relaunch while launching`.

[image: Terminate and relaunch eclipse visualization]